# Can we use V3 or Ved after the "after"

Tags: conjunctions, time-words

I read a sentence in a blog

> After **applied** for job in many companies, I was lucky enough to had
>   found a job related to my field of study.

Normally, we use after + Ving (in this case: applying), but I wonder that are there cases we can use "after + V3/Ved" (without subject)?

Updated: I found a question related to "after", and the answer is A
Just share to help us discuss more.

```
2. After ——— requests by local residents, the private library was opened to the public.
(A) repeated
(B) repeating
(C) repetition
(D) repeatedly
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Writing "After ***I*** applied would be correct, but ***after applied*** is incorrect. When you use the simple past tense, you must supply a subject with the verb. So, yes, you can use the simple past (tried, applied, died, etc) after the word "after", but you must supply a subject to go with the verb.

Comment: Thanks @DonB for your information, I just updated my post, could you please take a look at again. Sorry for any inconvenience

Comment: @LearningandWorking Using "repeated" changes things. "Repeated" used like this is an adjective-- not a verb. You're welcome. 

Comment: After + adjective: it's new to me, could you please share some pages/ or / the name of this grammar point, I can dig deeper into it.

Comment: @LearningandWorking Here is some basis information: https://www.grammarly.com/blog/adjective/

Comment: It seems the verb "repeated" is in the passive form , and reducing subject?

Comment: @LearningandWorking Read up on adjectives and how they are used. The passive participle of a verb can function as an adjective.